# How do i apply text-decoration:none; in my blogspot.?

Tags: html, css, blogs, blogspot

I want to apply `text-decoration: none;` properties for all link which is available in my blog,

Can anyone help me how can i do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside css, firsts lines:

```
a, a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```